# How to transform a Dictionary<object, string> to a Dictionary<object, List<string>> with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two methods that do the same thing, one works with a `Dictionary<object, List<string>>` and another one with a `Dictionary<object, string>` doing the same thing but iterating or not the list.

I want to reduce code duplication making just a method that works with `Dictionary<object, List<string>>` and transforming the `Dictionary<object, string>` to a `Dictionary<object, List<string>>` with a list with only one string.

How can I do the transform preferentially with LINQ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to *convert* or *transform*, not *cast*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well you can't *cast* the dictionary that way, but you could use:

```
var newDictionary = oldDictionary.ToDictionary(
                                       pair => pair.Key,
                                       pair => new List<string> { pair.Value });
```

Comment: @jv42: Of course, but you need to wait an amount of time before you can accept a question in SO. I've been here for a while :)

Comment: @SoMoS: that's a semi-automatic post on my part, when somebody with a not-that-great accept ratio gets a good answer. Sorry for the patronizing ;)

Comment: @jv42: I would like to have a greater accept ratio, unfortunately sometimes (25%) of the times I don't get a valid answer. Anyway, no problem man :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var newDict = oldDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new List<string> { x.Value });
```